# how to filter android app to be downloaded from google play to specific device?

Tags: android

I have to configure filter in my android app so it should only visible for specific set of devices(for eg. HTC, Samsung tabs etc..), assume other configurations like minsdk version etc.. are compatible with these set of devices, only i have to add one extra filter to make this app visible for some set of devices.

So scenario would be:

After uploading the app to Google play, when user tries to search the app it should only visible to the user who is having HTC ,Samsung tabs otherwise it should not be visible means if user searches this app using any other tab or phone it should not be visible for download.

Can anyone having idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think in code its possible at this point.

However when you upload the app to Google Play you can remove any and all devices of your choosing.  So just make sure the filters will allow your devices and don't worry about what else can use it.

The when you upload it into Android Developer Console you will see something like this:
[image: adc]

Then click "Show devices"

[image]

Then just exclude the ones you don't want.